# Jquery mobile + phonegap layout on emulator not same on device

Tags: android-layout, jquery-mobile, cordova, emulation

I have a simple application where im trying to just show some text, a slider, and a yellow button using jquery, and making it into a native app using phonegap.
It looks fine on my emulator

But on my device it looks really sad. No yellow button, no slider, just a plain white background and blue links in place of what should have been the slider and the button.

Im using a samsung galaxy S.
Could someone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: are you using local js/css files for jquery mobile or fetching them from their cdn link??

Comment: local javascript and css files

Comment: can you put source of your main html file??